# Why are "indemnify" and "condemn" spelled differently?

Tags: etymology, verbs, suffixes, transitive-verbs, derivational-morphology

Comparing the words *indemnify* and *condemn*:

- Both contain *demn* as a root
- Both are transitive verbs

Why is one spelled differently from the other – why not *indemn*, or *condemnify*?

Comment: Just as an FYI, you are confusing affix with root. There are three types of affixes: prefixes (attached to beginning of the root), suffixes (attached to end of root) and infixes (attached inside a root).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the root words are, respectively, Latin *indemnis* (adj.), and Latin *condemnare* (v.).  So *condemn* (*con* = "with", *demn* = "hurt") in Latin is the base of the verb, and needs only an ending to become a complete verb. When a word is transliterated to English, any ending is dropped, in this case resulting in *condemn*.  (Note that the process involves a Latin verb becoming an English verb.)

However, the base *indemn* (*in* = "not", *demn* = "hurt") was apparently (for reasons unknown to me) not chosen from a verb but from an adjective.  When this happens, an English adjective-to-verb ending is appended to the word (*indemn*); in this case, *-ify* was chosen to turn the adjective into a verb - hence *indemnify*. (Here, note that the process involves a Latin *adjective* becoming an English verb.)

Comment: Very nice!  There's also indemnity, making it a noun.

Comment: drɱ65 δ: Excellent, thanks. Next I'll have to read up on the relation between affixes and root. Embarrasingly, I wasn't aware of root before. Thus, double thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Indemnify* comes from the Latin *indemnus, indemnum*; the *-nus* and *-num* depend on the case of the word, so *-nify* is actually an ending, and not part of the regular *-mn* spelling or pronunciation. Though they both have been derived from *damnus* (*to penalize*), *indemnify* is taken from the noun *indemnity*, and *condemn* is a verb.